# how to divide uiview in two triangleview and get click on both of that trainge in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

[image]

how to divide uiview in two triangleview and get click on both of that trainge in swift 
.i explianed my question in below image

Comment: Search for bazier path and masking properties of view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect touch in triangle area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001487/how-to-detect-touch-in-triangle-area)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by core graphics. Create triangle view using path and lines as defined here:

[Triangle UIView - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650343/triangle-uiview-swift)

And then add tap gesture on view to get an action of UIView.

Comment: The motive is to solve the problem. When code has already been written in the linked question then what is the meaning of writing it again.

Comment: What in case that person delete his question?

Comment: @Ankitchauhan If `code has already been written in the linked question` then the right thing to do is *not* to post an answer with a link, but to flag the question as duplicate of your link.